# is $x_{n}\ll \overline{x}_{n}^{2}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

This question is a cross-post from MSE, cause I didn't get any answer there. I hope it is well suited for MO:

Let $(x_{n})_{n\ge 1}$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers and $\displaystyle{\overline{x}_{n}:=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}$. Suppose furthermore that $\forall\varepsilon\gt 0, \ \ n.\overline{x}_{n}\ll_{\varepsilon}n^{1+\varepsilon}$. Does it entail that $x_{n}\ll \overline{x}_{n}^{2}$?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I think I must clear up my idea here. Writing $m_{n}:=\dfrac{x_{1}+x_{n}}{2}$ and using the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, one gets $x_{1}.x_{n}\le m_{n}^{2}$. My idea is that, under the growth condition above, $m_{n}$ is roughly of the same order of magnitude as $\overline{x}_{n}$.

Comment: What does $\ll$ mean?

Comment: Why there are number theory tags here?

Comment: $x\ll y$ means the same thing as $x=O(y)$. I added the number theory tags as number theorists are rather familiar with this notation, and the terms of the sequence I consider are positive integers.

Comment: I suppose $x_n$ is not strictly increasing

Comment: Not necessarily, indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Let $(y_k)$ be a rapidly increasing sequence of positive integers, and for $y_k\leq n<y_{k+1}$ put $x_n:=y_k$. Note that $(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers satisfying $x_n\leq n$. In particular, $\overline{x}_{n}<n/2$. On the other hand, for $n:=y_k$ we have $x_n=y_k$, while $\overline{x}_{n}<1+y_{k-1}$. Hence $x_{n}\ll \overline{x}_{n}^{2}$ would imply that $y_k\ll y_{k-1}^2$ which is not always true. For a concrete counterexample take $y_k:=2^{3^k}$.

Comment: Thank you but does your proposed counterexample meet the requirement $n.\overline{x}_{n}\ll_{\varepsilon} n^{1+\varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon\gt 0$? It doesn't look obvious to me.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: My example satisfies the stronger bound $x_n\leq n$ which clearly implies $\overline{x}_{n}<n/2$.